# Exporting two slightly different namespaces from one CLI/C++ managed wrapper

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2017, namespaces

I have a native C++ library for which I created a managed wrapper in CLI/C++. It has been working well until I decided to extend it with additional sub-namespaces. The new namespace is not visible from my C# .NET project.
Here is a similar structure:

```
namespace A
{
    namespace B
    {
        public ref class X {...};
        public ref class Y {...};
        public ref class Z {...};
    }
}
namespace A
{
    namespace C
    {
        public ref class X {...};
        public ref class Y {...};
        public ref class Z {...};
    }
}
```

When I import it in a C# .NET project, in object browser I can see both A.B and A.C namespaces, but intellisense and also the compiler tells me that there is no such namespace as 'A.C'.

I tried renaming the namespaces, and I found that whichever namespace was renamed last it became visible, and the other one became invisible. Like I renamed A.C to A.D, and suddenly I was able to access A.D, but not A.B anymore. Then I renamed A.B to A.E, and suddenly A.E became visible, and A.D invisible.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update:** I removed all "using" statements from the CLI/C++ code and resolved the necessary dependencies locally (like System::String, etc...), because I was suspecting that maybe the way I was using other namespaces may have caused my problems. The answer is no. I am still having the same issue.

**Update 2:** I gave myself an answer because I thought I managed to resolve this issue, but I deleted it in the end. I think part of the problem is that I organised the nested namespaces into sub-folders, in which the filenames were exactly the same, so the compiler only took into account one filename once.
I think a working solution would be if I declared and defined both nested namespaces in the exact same header and cpp files, next to each other. I will try this later.

Comment: Seems like an intellisense bug, not a C++ or C# problem.   The compiler will correctly complain on attempt to use a declaration that the compiler hasn't seen, but should not require visibility of everything in a namespace to achieve that.

Comment: I also get the compiler error "The type or namespace name 'C' does not exist in the namespace 'A' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"
So it is not just intellisense.
Otherwise the two namespaces A.B and A.C are almost identical. They are declared identically, and their content is very similar. I can make either A.B visible or A.C, but not both.

Comment: That probably means you have code that is using something from `A::C` but (at the point where that code is compiled) there is no visibility of `A::C`.    Just adding a namespace `C` within namespace `A` in some place (e.g. a header) is not enough.    You need to ensure that all code which uses identifiers that are in `A::C` have visibility of `A::C`   e.g. the header that declares `A::C` and names within it needs to be included so the compiler has  visibility of those names.

Comment: The CLI/C++ wrapper builds 100% fine, as I have mentioned it above. Also, if I rename A.C to A.D (using refactoring in VS2017, that renames all occurences) then suddenly A.D becomes visible, and the previously visible A.B becomes invisible. So it appears that the namespaces individually are correct. All my cpp and h files use the namespace correctly. But somehow the fact that I have two namespaces at the same level is causing the problem. The header does not need to be visible, as I am using it from C# .NET, and my C# .NET project is not parsing C++ header files.

Comment: @Peter: Now that I am reading back my answers, I was not 100% clear about a couple of things, my apologies for that. So the compiler error was in my C# project, that was trying to use the wrapper. The wrapper was building fine from the beginning. The problems were in the C# project that was referencing the C++ wrapper.